# Plot a line graph, error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot

```
a<- c(2,2)
b<- c(3,4)
plot(a,b) # It works perfectly here
```

Then I tried:

```
t<-xy.coords(a,b)
plot(t) # It also works well here
```

Finally, I tried:

```
plot(t,1)
```

Now it shows me:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>         'x' and 'y' lengths differ

It does not work, inside t, **both a and b are of length 2**, why it showing me **x, y lengths differ?**

Comment: because length(t) is 4 and length(1) is 1.

Comment: Hi, my friend, I do 1 for type = 1, which is line plot

Comment: does this work? `plot(t[[1]], t[[2]], type="l")`

Answer (score 15):

`plot(t)` is in this case the same as

```
plot(t[[1]], t[[2]])
```

As the error message says, x and y differ in length and that is because you plot a list with length 4 against `1`:

```
> length(t)
[1] 4
> length(1)
[1] 1
```

In your second example you plot a list with elements named `x` and `y`, both vectors of length 2,
so `plot` plots these two vectors.

Edit:

If you want to plot lines use

```
plot(t, type="l")
```

Comment: This helped. I was getting similar error and tried this and adjusted my array length accordingly. Thank you.